# Back button issue in windows 8.1 app (PhoneGap)

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing a **Single page** app for **Windows Phone 8.1** in **PhoneGap** (HTML5 and Javascript). Everthing is working fine but the only **issue is coming in handling the back button** of my app.

Here is the code **structure** of my app(Single page App):

```
<body>

<div class="Page1">
    // Here is the code of First page of my app (Login Wizard.)
</div>

<div class="Page2">
    // Here is the code of Second page of my app
</div>

<div class="Page3">
    // Here is the code of Third page of my app
</div>

<div class="Page4">
    // Here is the code of Fourth page of my app
</div>

<div class="Page15">
    // Here is the code of Fifth page of my app
</div>

<div class="Page6">
    // Here is the code of Sixth page of my app
</div>

//And so on

</body>
```

[image]

I tried using several methods to handle it but nothing worked. Two of them are:

**First:**

```
  $(document).ready(function () { 
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", setOverrideBackbutton, false);
    });

function setOverrideBackbutton() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", backButtonTap, true);
}

/**
 * Callback after a backbutton tap on windows platforms.
 * Do nothing.
 */
function backButtonTap() {
    //Do not remove
    alert("back button clicked.");
}
```

Second:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
     element.on('click', function() {
         $window.history.back();
     });
 }
```

But i am not able to do so. i guess its because my app is a single page app. what should i do.

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: if the answer below satisfies your problem, please accept it as an answer, so that it can help other with the similar problem in future.

Answer (score 3):

Method for registering an event onBackKeyDown();

```
   if (device.platform == "windows") {
    // Get the back button working in WP8.1
    WinJS.Application.onbackclick = function () {
        onBackKeyDown();
        return true; // This line is important, without it the app closes.
    }
}
else {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}
```

Now just add a function to handle the onBackKeyDown event and that's it:

```
function onBackKeyDown() {
    // Back key pressed, do something here
}
```

Standard method to hook into the BackButton-Event would look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Cordova Back Button Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Call onDeviceReady when Cordova is loaded.
    //
    // At this point, the document has loaded but cordova-2.5.0.js has not.
    // When Cordova is loaded and talking with the native device,
    // it will call the event `deviceready`.
    //
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    // Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to call Cordova methods
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Register the event listener
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    }

    // Handle the back button
    //
    function onBackKeyDown() {
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad()">
  </body>
</html>
```